# Control Flow Graph : properly identify loop "condition"

Tags: loops, graph-theory, control-flow-graph

I have this C# code sample (but language is absolutely not important) :

```
 public static void NestedSimple(int[] a, int n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n && i < 12; i++)
        {
            a[i] += 1;
        }
    }
```

Once compiled, I get this IL :

```
IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: br.s IL_0017
    // loop start (head: IL_0017)
        IL_0005: nop
        IL_0006: ldarg.0
        IL_0007: ldloc.0
        IL_0008: ldelema [mscorlib]System.Int32
        IL_000d: dup
        IL_000e: ldind.i4
        IL_000f: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0010: add
        IL_0011: stind.i4
        IL_0012: nop
        IL_0013: ldloc.0
        IL_0014: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0015: add
        IL_0016: stloc.0

        IL_0017: ldloc.0
        IL_0018: ldarg.1
        IL_0019: bge.s IL_0022

        IL_001b: ldloc.0
        IL_001c: ldc.i4.s 12
        IL_001e: clt
        IL_0020: br.s IL_0023

        IL_0022: ldc.i4.0

        IL_0023: stloc.1
        IL_0024: ldloc.1
        IL_0025: brtrue.s IL_0005
    // end loop

    IL_0027: ret
```

which can be represented by this Control Flow Graph (reconstructed from IL, basic blocks are properly identified and domination relations computed by Lengauer-Tarjan) :

[image: Control Flow Graph]

The back edge is IL_0005 -> IL_0017 as IL_0005 dominates IL_0017 which means loop header is IL_0017.

How can I identify that every block between IL_0017 and IL_0023 belong to the loop exit condition and not the plain body ?

My intuition is that IL_0005 is the actual body and the only edge going to IL_0005 starts from IL_0023, meaning that all blocks between IL_0017 and IL_0023 are part of the condition.

However -> it doesn't rely on theory and depends on C# -> MSIL compiler behavior.

Is there something solid that I can implement ?

So far, my code looks like :

```
// if back edge (n->d where d dominates n) then we have a loop
            if ((block.JumpTarget != null && block.JumpTarget.Dominates(block)) ||
                (block.Next != null && block.Next.Dominates(block)))
            {
                var header = block.JumpTarget != null ? block.JumpTarget : block.Next;
                var tail = block;
                var visited = new HashSet<BasicBlock> { header, tail};
                var stack = new Stack<BasicBlock>();
                
                // populate body
                stack.Push(block);
                while (stack.Any())
                {
                    var n = stack.Pop();
                    if(!visited.Contains(n))
                    {
                        visited.Add(n);
                        foreach(var p in n.Predecessors)
                        {
                            stack.Push(p);
                        }
                    }
                }
                var body = visited.OrderBy(b => b.Id).ToList();
           /// HERE : how can I identify loop condition ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't if this answer your question, but it's possible to unroll the loop like the following (practically "extracting" the boolean condition)

```
   IL_000
    |
   IL_0017
    |     \
   IL_001b  IL_0022
    |      /
 - IL_0023 ----------.
'   |                |
|  IL_0005           |
|   |                |
|  IL_0017           |
|   |     \          |
|  IL_001b  IL_0022  |
'  /       /         |
 \--------/          |
                     |
                    IL_0027
```

you see that `(i < n && i <12)` is encoded inside the `17`, `1b`, `22` and the `if` by the `23` block, becoming the head of the loop.

My reasoning is that a `while` loop is encoded by the following graph

[image]

I don't know an algorithm with only basic blocks, decompilers usually "simplify" them: in your case all the blocks I have extracted could be collapsed into a single statemement and merged into `IL_0023`.

Comment: Indeed. You mean that the if statement (23) can be merged by everything between it and it's immediate dominator (17) ?

Comment: yeah, but as I said, without "simplifying" them and merge them inside the `if` I don't think you can obtain a `while()` that for me is identified by the graph structure.